# Permanently add a new column to the tibble and this column should record the collection times as days

Tags: r

I am very new to R so have limited experience with R.

I have a set of date with 71 obs and 8 variables, I need to use a certain date which is 2020-05-14 to write a single line of code to permanently add a new column called Days, and this column should record the collection time in days prior to the date stated above, my data is called minktrim, how do i do this?

this is my data:

## A tibble: 71 x 8

Accession Release_Date Species Length Geo_Location Host  Isolation_Source Collection_Date
                                       
1 MW059036  2020-11-01T… Severe…  29846 United King… Homo… NA               2020-01-29
2 MW041156  2020-09-28T… Severe…  29870 United King… Homo… NA               2020-05-01
3 MT594401  2020-09-25T… Severe…  29804 France       Homo… NA               2020-04-20
4 MT594402  2020-09-25T… Severe…  29804 France       Homo… NA               2020-04-20
5 MT845877  2020-08-29T… Severe…  29835 Germany      Homo… oronasopharynx   2020-03-31
6 MT845878  2020-08-29T… Severe…  29835 Germany      Homo… NA               2020-04-08
7 MT913119  2020-08-24T… Severe…  29870 Germany      Homo… swab             2020-03-20
8 MT873892  2020-08-11T… Severe…  29821 United King… Homo… NA               2020-03-18
9 MT704816  2020-08-03T… Severe…  29870 Germany: Ba… Homo… NA               2020-03-18
10 MT704817  2020-08-03T… Severe…  29870 Germany: Ba… Homo… NA               2020-03-20

## … with 61 more rows

info given from my tutor I tried the following code which doesn't work.

minkclean <-minktrim%>%mutate(Days=ymd(20200514)-Collection_Date)%>%filter(Days>=0)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example with `dput`  i.e. `dput(head(minktrim))` so that it can be tested

Comment: `ymd(20200514)-Release_Date&Collection_Date` is confusing. `ymd(20200514)-Release_Date` should return a date-difference object (usually numeric with units), but `&` is a logical-and operator. While that can make sense in some contexts, I don't see it here. Further, your code is not syntactically correct, `mutate(...)filter(...)` is not right. It's difficult to help you when we cannot be certain if errors are due to the problem we see (like that) or something else that we don't see.

Comment: ive edited my post sorry as i have now said in my post im new to R and not very good at it hopefully it will make a bit more sense if not please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `Collection_Date` a date too:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

minkclean <- minktrim %>%
  mutate(Days = ymd(20200514) - ymd(Collection_Date)) %>%
  filter(Days >= 0)
```

Comment: Hi Donna, if you're happy with an answer you should be able to accept it if you'd like.